# WooCommerce - Clarification on post/zip code validation, and how to hook into/override

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce store, and have an issue we'd like to resolve, and also noticed an issue which seems to be 'out of the box' with WooCommerce, that I was hoping we could override and fix.

During the checkout process, the user is presented with a Post code/zip code field, that changes based on the country selected.

There's some basic validation over whether the field has a value or not, for example, if the field has a value, the border would go green indicating that the field was correct, this all seems to be within checkout.js (I've used this to succesfully override most of the issues i needed, i.e. phone/email validation, but postcode doesn't seem to be included).

There also seems to be some further validation that goes on with the post/zipcode which can be seen inside 'class-wc-validation.php' with a few functions for 'is_postcode()', 'is_gb_postcode()', and also 'format_postcodes()'.

If the user proceeds with an invalid postcode, for example, i'll use United Kingdom as my chosen country, and input the postcode field with 'E1', the postcode field shows with a green border, as if it's valid, but upon trying to proceed, WooCommerce throws an error for the invalid postcode, but leaves the field with a green border. (see screenshot)

[image: screenshot showing error]

What I'd like to do, is hook into when this validation occurs, and highlight the postcode field with a red border, and preferably add an error message below the field.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of how this could be done? I'm assuming it might be something the 'woocommerce_validate_postcode' filter could help with, but any direction would be hugely helpful!

EDIT:
Based on the comment below from CBroe, I've looked further and, I think I should be using the 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation' action.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 
    'validate_postcode', 10, 2);

function validate_postcode( $fields, $errors ){
   // do check on validation here and add error label to field and change class name of wrapper to invalid.
}
```

Using the above, is there anyway I could print out a list of $fields and $errors in order to see what's happening?

Thanks guys!

Comment: The filter itself just allows you to overwrite the true/false result of this validation. But if you want to style the field differently based on that, and perhaps even add the error message below it, you'll have to look elsewhere, and figure out where from that validation gets called.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for that, I've edited the original question to include some more detail and another hook that I think is more in the right direction.

Comment: Try a `var_dump($fields, $errors); exit;` in that function, to see what those variables contain. (exit, so that it stops further execution there, that should make it easier to find the debug output. Maybe wrap into a `<pre>` element for readability.) Or, of course, use an IDE with a proper debugger like XDebug integrated, then you can inspect such variables "live."